Python package installation using pip
I use Python both from Jupyter Notebook as well as directly from the terminal. My Python version is 3.10.12.
I install packages both from the terminal (using pip install <package-name>) as well as from the notebook (using !pip install <package-name>). Mistakenly, I have also installed some packages earlier with sudo as well. As a result, I have versions of the same package available at multiple places: at /home/username/ as well as inside /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages,. Note that, I didn't have any environment created as well. So I think all the packages that I have externally involved are messed up among the system packages. As a result, I am facing conflicts and sometimes installed packages are not being found in most of the cases from inside Jupyter Notebook.
My question is:
. How to clean this mess up?
. Can someone please provide the instructions to be followed from the beginning after installing Python?

For the installed pip using sudo, you can uninstalled it using this command
python -m pip uninstall 'package-name'

You can setup env variable using python to install the python package so you can install the package with your own independent set of Python packages installed.
first, create virtualenv
python3 -m venv path/to/venv
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install xyz

exit from virtual environment
deactivate

